# Reopen ActionMode (or CAB) after onDestroyActionMode is called

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

Let's see this situation: you've got a CAB open with DONE & DISCARD options on a screen with a form to be filled and you won't accept an error value for a field. Hence, the user should either fill in a valid value (and press Back/Done for it to be accepted) or press Discard on the CAB.

Pressing DONE initiates `onDestroyActionMode()` immediately, after which the CAB is closed.
So, this is the place (beside the `onBackPressed()`) where the check for validity is initiated.

The problem is, if creating a new ActionMode there (if the form validity check fails), the recursive loop will be started (as the new CAB will first start closing the old one and so on) --> StackOverflowError.

I tried creating a state variable to prevent the StackOverflowError, but in that case it works only every second time (and only `onBackPressed()`) :-/

So, **the question**: how do I keep the CAB open (or how to re-open a new one) immediately after `onDestroyActionMode()` was called on it?

Comment: You should rethink your current logic. Reopening the CAB when the user enters something wrong doesn't sound to clear from a user experience point of view(as I don't think the CAB is proper for a data input form). You might want to do the validation on the spot when the user enters data and if the user still keeps clicking done show him a message that the input is not correct(although seeing a real time validity indicator would probably make him not click done).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
The CAB is a proper pattern for such scenario (creating an entry).
The field in question already has the validation and the indication of error. The problem is that the proper operation would be to always save/create data when the user presses Back button (same as Done), but the error forbids this operation to be completed (because of key violation, for example). Hence the want/need to keep the CAB after the Back/Done was pressed with error.

Comment: I am aware of another possibility: to discard the data with error when the Back/Done was pressed and to notify the user about it, but that seems a bit clumsy as the user did have an intention (to edit/create the entry) and doing the auto-discard seems to be taking that intention too lightly.

Comment: "The CAB is a proper pattern for such scenario (creating an entry)" -- DONE & DISCARD is not an action mode/CAB, but rather a stylized action bar, as Roman Nurik described a year ago: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/R49wVvcDoEW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first commenter is indeed correct. Action modes are transient and can be finished by the user at any time by design. They're for representing something like a batch selection that you can add to or remove from before taking an action on the full set, mail triage and text editing being two examples. Finishing an action mode should be non-destructive, just like canceling a dialog. It should not be treated as a confirmation step.

Speaking of text editing, you're heavily implying that your form involved here contains text fields. What happens when a user highlights some text and the TextView starts its own editing action mode? Starting an action mode will implicitly finish any current action mode.

You should use another affordance to express an edit in progress.

Comment: Will rework the CAB to AB (as @CommonsWare rightfully observed) and will make it behave leniently towards errors, i.e. discard the form when data has errors when the Back/Done was pressed and notify/toast the user about it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the core question: how can you recreate an ActionMode after a back press:

You can postDelayed a Runnable to a Handler to recreate an ActionMode. The delay needed can vary a little between devices, I've found 200ms to work with everything I've tried. In an Activity or FragmentActivity try these snippets:

```
RepeatActionModeRunnable mRepeatActionModeRunnable;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRepeatActionModeRunnable);
    super.onPause();
}

private class RepeatActionModeRunnable implements Runnable {
    ActionMode.Callback mRepeatActionMode;
    public RepeatActionModeRunnable(ActionMode.Callback actionMode) {
        mRepeatActionMode = actionMode;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mActionMode = startActionMode(mRepeatActionMode);
    }
}
```

Then in onDestroyActionMode you can use this when you need to (i.e. you'll no doubt want some logic wrapping this to detect if it should or shouldn't be recreated):

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRepeatActionModeRunnable);
mRepeatActionModeRunnable = new RepeatActionModeRunnable(new SomeActionMode());
mHandler.postDelayed(mRepeatActionModeRunnable, 200);
```

As for whether CAB is or isn't to be used for forms/data input, such situations are well suited to a "call for action" and that is also the reason d'etre for the ActionMode pattern. The existence of hurdles/nuances/bugs such as recreating after back button press and if a user selects text to edit should not constitute rationale for it to not be OK to use, rather for it to be seen as perhaps not the path of least resistance in terms of a solution (it's a challenge!). The existence of the 'Done & Discard' pattern alone also shouldn't constitute rationale for not using ActionMode for situations involving data input. These are all possibilities that may suit your situation better or worse rather than a right or wrong way.

PS: regarding how to deal with TextSelectionCAB, here's a solution: [Detect ActionMode nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567783/detect-actionmode-nesting/19125698#19125698)

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer according to question. Hopefully someone could benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You can do something like this, then there won't be StackOverflowException anymore.:

```
 @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            //your code
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startSupportActionMode(mActionCallBack);
                }
            });
        }
```